# How to get lists of all Telegram channels on a regular basis?

Tags: database, telegram, channel, catalog, telegram-api

I want to receive lists of telegram channels on the basis of **telemetr.me**, **tgstat.ru** or **telega.in**.

I don't know how this is implemented in these services, but I can imagine 3 options:

1. **The user himself adds** his channel to the service *(but I know for
   sure that this is not the only option, because on the same Telemetr
   there is my channel that I did not add)*
2. The **owners and admins** of the
   service manually add all the channels on their own *(then it’s a
   matter of time, because if not 1,000,000 channels, then definitely
   more than 500,000; and the question of data: how
   do they know that such a channel exists and can be added to base?)*
3. And the third option, the most logical one: somewhere there is a
   **database of all telegram channels** that you can connect to and work
   with.

Here, in fact, the third option I'm interested in.

Who faced? Who implemented this issue in their projects?
**How to implement this in my case through Python, or Telegram Api, or something else?**